# How to remove current tasks from cron service?

Tags: command-line, cron, ram

My main problem is that cron jobs won't run automatically but they run fine from the command line.
When I run `service cron status` on my Ubuntu 18.10 (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-25-generic x86_64), I get this :

[image: output of the command service cron status]

I think it's not normal to have 4915 tasks while the limit is 4915.

Here is the output of `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

[image: output of grep CRON /var/log/syslog]

While searching what can't fork means it seems that I have a memory issue, so i run `ulimit -a` and here is the output:

[image: output of ulimit -a]

It may be a permissions problem or a misconfiguration. I really don't know what caused this issue since many people are using the same server.

@FedonKadifeli (Here is what you've asked.):

```
command : ps -ef | grep -c cron
output : 3
```

Comment: You have 4915 cron processes! That is really a problem! Please, [edit] your original post and paste `ps -ef | grep -c cron` output ***in text*** (and not image) to get an idea...

Comment: This might be relevant: [What causes cron to continuously send mail and how can I disable it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202190/65304)

Answer (score 1):

Use `crontab -e` to edit your cron tasks, commenting unneccessary tasks and combining a lot of tasks into fewer using scripts to combine them.

If you have admin privileges, you could also check other users' cron tasks numbers and tell them to optimize tasks number by using scripts: `crontab -e -u user`

To see all cron jobs, you could try `cat var/spool/cron/crontabs/*/*` depending your crontab files location.

> To see which "cron" processes belong to user :
>
> ```
> pgrep -u username cron
> ```
>
> To kill those processes:
>
> ```
> pkill -u username cron
> ```

[Reference](https://serverfault.com/a/622806/521673)